# <%# Bind([ReqPo!ItemId])%> doesnt work

Tags: asp.net, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, enterprise-portal

In Dynamics ax Enterprise Portal I have created a templatefield in AxGridView. Seems everything ok, but when i try to enter some value to this textbox (manually or through lookup), it doesnt bind to ReqPo!ItemId field. Checked that with info(strfmt("%1", ReqPo.ItemId))); in validateWrite method on ReqPo dataset - it prints nothing; What i'm missing?

```
<asp:TemplateField ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" HeaderText="<%$ AxLabel:@SYS12836 %>" Visible="true">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxFilterItemId" CssClass="AxInputField" 
                Columns="<%$ AxDataSet:ReqTransPo.ReqTrans.ReqPo!ItemId.DisplayLength %>" 
                Enabled="<%$ AxDataSet:ReqTransPo.ReqTrans.ReqPo!ItemId.AllowEdit %>" 
                MaxLength="<%$ AxDataSet:ReqTransPo.ReqTrans.ReqPo!ItemId.StringSize %>" 
                Text='<%# Bind("[ReqPo!ItemId]") %>'> 
            </asp:TextBox>
            <dynamics:AxLookup
                ID="AxLookup3" runat="server" OnLookup="Item_lookup" TargetControlId="TextBoxFilterItemId"
                CssClass="AxLookupButtonBF" HoverCssClass="AxLookupButtonHoverBF" ShowFilter="True">
            </dynamics:AxLookup>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="ItemIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[ReqPo!ItemId]") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the ItemId field from the table ReqPo. If you locate that field in the Data Dictionary you will discover that the field does not allow editing.

As AxGridView only supports editing, which leads me to the conclusion that you are trying the break the data integrity rules of the application.

if this is the case, it is obviously not possible.

Comment: well, actually this is not the case, Because I made ReqPo.ItemId field AllowEdit = true, AllowEditOnCreate = true in AOT on ReqPo table. But Trying to edit or create the line in AxGridView leads to the same warning: "Field ItemId must be filled in". So i don't understand why Bind() method doesn't work? Any more ideas?

Comment: so, seems that shoud be something wrong with axapta side programming, if there's everything ok ...